# Calculating Difference Between Same Colums SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table named terminal_infos.

[image: terminal_infos]

Let me explain the how this table works: There approx. 350 terminals with you can seperate with terminal_id. About every 2-3 minutes, 350 terminal information is inserting by a program. You can see which terminal (terminal_id) used how many data, how many capacity they  have, are they working (is_up) and the date of the insertion.

What i am trying to achieve is: I want to get difference of overall_usage between 2 date of all terminals. As you can see there are already 24 million rows at this table. At every 3 minute, 350 new row is going to be inserted to this table.

At this pic, you can see any duplicate terminal_id because it only has 10 rows, but if i send a pic of the SELECT * from terminal_id limit by 400; you would see 50 duplicated terminal_id with different time, overall_usage and is_up.

What is the best way or any way to achieve this?

Comment: What results do you want?  Your question is not clear.

Comment: Provide a sample - CREATE TABLE script, INSERT INTO script (for 2 terminals, 3-5 rows each), and show desired output for this data with some explanations. *I want to get difference of overall_usage between 2 date of all terminals.* What is "overall_usage" for a date, not for a row? SUM for all overall_usage values within the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to find the difference of `overall_usage` column for all the `tid` between two specific dates. Since there are approximately 480 rows for a tid in a specific days. I have calculated the average of that day then subtracted the average of overall_usage from the average of overall_usage for another day. Hope it's what you are looking for.

```
select tid,avg(a.overall_usage)-avg(b.overall_usage)overall_usage_difference
(select tid,overall_usage from terminal_infos where cast([date] as date)='2021-06-18') a
inner join
(select tid,overall_usage from terminal_infos where cast([date] as date)='2021-06-17') b
on a.tid=b.tid
group by tid
```

Comment: This question *seems* to be about MySQL